How can I use lsp-docker with pylsp or pyright?
For the life of me, I cannot get lsp-docker to work. My goal is to use lsp-docker with lsp-pyright and ruff server, but I'd be happy with just pyright or pylsp. I can always run ruff with flymake.
The first step is getting lsp-mode connected to the webserver's container which has both pylsp and pyright as a dev dependency.
Note, I'm also new to Python and Mac coming from a JVM and Lisp on Linux background so I may be making Python or Mac errors. I am also completely new to developing inside containers, I have previously only used containers for deployments.
Here is my attempt to get pylsp working. I believe this should be starting a new container dedicated for pylsp then I'd try to integrate into my webserver's container next. But I can't even get a basic container lsp server to work.

(use-package lsp-mode
  :commands lsp lsp-deferred
  ;; :hook ((python-mode . lsp-deferred)
  ;;        (python-ts-mode . lsp-deferred))
  :init
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l"
        lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable nil
        lsp-modeline-diagnostics-enable nil
        )
  )

(use-package lsp-docker
  :init
  (defvar lsp-docker-client-packages
    '(lsp-pylsp))
  (setq lsp-docker-client-configs
        '((:server-id pylsp :docker-server-id pylsp-docker :server-command "pylsp")))
  :config
  (lsp-docker-init-clients
   :path-mappings '(("/Users/me/code/app" . "/app"))
   :client-packages lsp-docker-client-packages
   :client-configs lsp-docker-client-configs)
  )


*lsp-log*
Command "semgrep lsp" is not present on the path.
Command "ruff server" is present on the path.
Command "pyls" is not present on the path.
Command "pyright-langserver --stdio" is present on the path.
Command "pylsp" is present on the path.
Command "semgrep lsp" is not present on the path.
Command "ruff server" is present on the path.
Command "pyls" is not present on the path.
Command "pyright-langserver --stdio" is present on the path.
Command "pylsp" is present on the path.

Found the following clients for /Users/me/code/app/code/api/something/schema.py: (server-id ruff, priority -2), (server-id pyright, priority 2), (server-id pylsp-docker, priority 10), (server-id pylsp, priority -1)

The following clients were selected based on priority: (server-id pylsp-docker, priority 10), (server-id ruff, priority -2)

Creating watchers for following 13 folders:

...


*pylsp-docker::stderr*

WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "pylsp": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Process pylsp-docker stderr finished


Any thoughts?
